# get the height of horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I encountered a problem where I need to know of the height of horizontal scrollbar.

This Q&A suggests that you should use `clientHeight` property and calculate difference. Unfortunately this does not work anymore as is evident here https://jsfiddle.net/fn8naww8/

So how can I get the height of scrollbar?

**EDIT**: OSX does not differentiate between offsetHeight and clientHeight.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
#content{
  height:100%;
  width:200%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}
```

Comment: offsetHeight returns 100px for main div and because of scroll 83 for inner

Comment: thanks, I believe that only works on windows.

Comment: I have checked with some osx chrome extensions and I posted answer where it works but with osx extensions it shows 100px for both. On windows 83 for content.

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
var horizontalScrollbarHeight = wrapper.offsetHeight - wrapper.clientHeight;
```

or like:

```
var horizontalScrollbarHeight = wrapper.offsetHeight - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(wrapper, null).getPropertyValue("height"), 10);
```

Both will return `~17` if the scrollbar size was not altered by CSS like by using `::-webkit-scrollbar`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Thanks. This approaches return 0. On OSX scrollbars only show when you actually scroll.

Comment: @sanjihan sadly I don't have any OSX near hand

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#wrapper")).height);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("#content")).height);
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
#content{
  height:100%;
  width:200%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

This will return 100px for wrapper and 83px for inner.

Answer (score -2):

There is a magic number: “17px”.
Seems this height/width does not change even if you resize the browser window.
And it works on Chrome fine with my test.

Comment: What if you change the scrollbar size in CSS? Than 17 is not *magic* any more.

Comment: Is 17px browser independent?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If you can change the scroll bar size, then you can use that variable then.

Comment: @meetlost no, because if you change a scrollbar size in one browser, it  does not means that in another one you won't see the OS default scrollbar.

Comment: @sanjihan I am not sure. Just post my use case. And I think if there is one really portable way to get this value, then this is not a problem anymore. seems scroll bar itself is browser dependent.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okay, but how to change the scroll bar size as you say? I think this need testing on different browsers.

Comment: Well, if you do a research (or see my answer) you'll find `::-webkit-scrollbar`. If you set i.e: `height: 8px;` the scrollbar will have 8px height. But only if webkit browsers since it's a non standard property. So no. Forget about the magic 17.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Web UI adjustment for different browsers is a hard progress. I think the realistic solution should be different part mix together. Say, use browser dependent properties and may browser independent properties as well, even some magic. Finally users can get the good experience on the mix. But if there is really a portable solution, just use it.